# How to change math function after closing "Add function surface"

Tags: mesh, mathematics

When I choose to add **Z** or **X, Y, Z** function, "Add function surface" menu appears in the bottom-left corner. But once I click outside the object it disappears and I can no longer change the function. So how do I open that menu again to change the function or where can I find menu to redefine the function without adding new object whenever I want?

Comment: ... for the XYZ math surface I  find using the text editor more convenient than the UI for complex (or verbose) equations.   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/205868/15543  (Note: not forwarded as an answer as  running the script creates a new object)

Comment: @Gorgious, oh, thanks. But it is said that I can change a function only if its creation was the last action. Otherwise there is no way to redefine. If it is so, that yes, it is the answer.

Comment: @batFINGER, seems useful and nice :). I'll try it out. Thanks